# Array Multidimensional

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional

Estoy haciendo un programa para guiarme por los fundamentos basicos de los arrays multidimensionales. El programa es muy sencillo y funciona bien, bueno, medio bien.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public class guia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] numeros; //declaración array con dos dimensiones
        int f, c; //para recorrer el array. F = filas; C = columnas
        numeros = new int[2][3]; // Tendrá 2 filas y 3 columnas

        for (f = 0; f < numeros.length; f++) { //primero recorre las filas
            for (c = 0; c < numeros[f].length; c++) { //despues recorre cada columna que haya en esa fila
                
                numeros [f][c]=0; // rellena todo el array con 0
            }

        }
        
        //Muestra el array
        for (f = 0; f < numeros.length; f++) {
            for (c = 0; c < numeros[f].length; c++) {
                
                System.out.println(numeros[f][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

Pero me muestra el array asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En lugar de como yo quiero, que sería así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción `println()` sirve para imprimir cada parámetro que se le pasa en una línea. Cambia esa instrucción que hay dentro de los dos bucles anidados por `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 1):

Te he hecho una modificación para que se haga como tú quieres:

```
 int[][] numeros; // declaración array con dos dimensiones
    int f,c; // para recorrer el array. F = filas; C = columnas
    numeros = new int[2][3]; // Tendrá 2 filas y 3 columnas

    for(f = 0;f < numeros.length;f++)
    { // primero recorre las filas
      for(c = 0;c < numeros[f].length;c++)
      { // despues recorre cada columna que haya en esa fila

        numeros[f][c] = 0; // rellena todo el array con 0
      }

    }

    // Muestra el array

    // En vez de ir imprimendo las columnas, las juntamos en un StringBuilder
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for(f = 0;f < numeros.length;f++)
    {
      for(c = 0;c < numeros[f].length;c++)
      {

        res.append(numeros[f][c]);
        res.append(" ");
      }
      // Borramos los espacios del final de la fila y añadimos un salto de línea
      res.trimToSize();
      res.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Como resultado, devuelte esto:

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```